# Sleep mode in ATMEGA16 not working

Tags: avr, c, atmega, timer, sleep

I am trying to put my controller in sleep mode and waking it up on a certain number of timer overflow. The code is as below:

```
//*******TIMER 2 INITILIZATION  will be used
    TCCR2=0X07;   //clock source select, prescaler
    TIMSK=0X40;  //timer 2 interrupt selected
    TCNT2=0X00;   // timer resistor
    sei();

    // controller sleep mode
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_SAVE); // sleep mode selected
    sleep_enable();  // set SE bit
    sleep_cpu(); // sleep mode activated
    do 
    {
        if(count>=1000) //  min delay
        {
            sleep_disable();   // SE bit reset
            _delay_ms(1000);
            print("waking up.....");
            _delay_ms(2000);
            cmd(0xc0);
            print("AT+CFUN=1");
            _delay_ms(1000);
            transmit("AT+CFUN=1\r\n");
            _delay_ms(1000);
            _delay_ms(2000);count=0;
            break;              

        }
        else
        {
            print("sleep");
            sleep_enable();
            sleep_cpu();                
        }       

    } while (1);
```

the corresponding ISR is as follows

```
ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect)
{
    count++;

}
```

The problem it is not coming out of sleep mode.

I am using internal clock 8MHz and timer2.
edit: i found this description in datasheet ,so this means i have to use asynchronous clock for timer 2 (i.e provided by external crystal osc).Is there any way i can do this with the help of internal clock.
[image: power save mode description in datasheet]

Comment: Why do you return(count) out of interrupt service? It is pretty meaningless. Also, is it declared as volatile?

Comment: i have declared count as integer type globally with initially value 0.the return function i was using just to check might be using return it will work .but i will remove it.

Comment: remove the return(count); line from ISR and add 'volatile' before 'int count' declaration.

Comment: Also, where do you reset the 'count' variable?

Comment: still doesnt work .i am not resetting the count variable.is this the reason code not working?

Comment: Because once the variable count reaches 1000, the condition if(count>=1000) would trigger just non-stop. Unless this is what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: No, you cannot do this. Period. Look at your own yellow highlight. Halts ALL CLOCKS except Async. There is no internal clock to use. None. It's ALL halted.

Comment: one concept i want to reconfirm async clock is only provided with external oscillator or it can be through internal osc?

Comment: How much low power do you need ? (please do not answer "best possible").Have you read datasheet chapter "Minimizing power consumption" ? Of course sleep is important but it may be optimized a lot more

Comment: In datasheet thi is given :Power-down Mode: < 1μA. so i am also expecting the same. 
I did some research and used external xtal of 32.7khz and setting the flag bit accordingly  now it is working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, timer 2 can only be used with external Xtal in power save mode.

- Either use the Idle sleep mode (you may slow down MCU frequency before entering sleep to gain consumption)
- Or you could use the watchdog to wake you up (unsing interrupt and reset mode). Of course this will be a bit less precise but you could use power down sleep mode which is even better.

Comment: I did some research and used external xtal of 32.7khz  and setting the flag bit accordingly. now it is working properly.

Comment: I was in need of the minimum possible power and power down mode is fulfilling my need <1μA. now its working thankyou